# Where does the MiG-29 store fuel?

Tags: fuel, fuel-tanks, mig-29

How does the MiG-29 fuel system work? Like, where does it store around 300 cubic feet of fuel?

Also, which fuel does it use? Is JP4 preferable?

Comment: I'll comment on the "also" question, as it's not worth an answer. MiG-29, like most Russian/Soviet jets, normally uses the [TS-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_fuel#TS-1) kerosene. It's closest common analog is Jet-A1, but like anything in aviation, every type of fuel has to be specifically approved. Jet-A1 and JP-8 are approved, AFAIK. I'm not sure about JP-4, but it's certainly not 'preferable'. In practice though, a jet engine will burn almost anything, and in times of war you can even use diesel fuel.

Answer (score 5):

Like every plane, the MiG-29 stores its fuel in fuel tanks ;)

On a more serious manner:

Generally speaking, there are 6 internal fuel tanks: 4 distributed around the fuselage and 1 in each wing.

Later versions (namely the SMT) have larger internal fuel capacity thanks to the enlarged spine.

The exact locations of these tanks can be seen in this cutaway [(src)](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2e/8d/33/2e8d33d37523031c98998778d319c217.jpg): 63, 72, 93, 107, 187.

In addition to these, the 29 can also carry 3 (1 in the very early versions) jettisonable external fuel tanks.

[image: MIG-29 cutaway diagram]

Comment: can you please share a picture?

Comment: @AdeelAhsan Please try a simple web search for "Mig 29 fuel tanks", this is a topic with many existing answers and resources.

Comment: @AdeelAhsan a picture of what? I provided a link to a very detailed cutaway.

Comment: you  should also mention external fuel tanks (that can be jettisoned).

Comment: To avoid link-rot, you should include the picture (with attribution) in your post.

Comment: @ManuH updated..

Comment: Please note that on later models the upper air intake functionality (#55 that gill-like part) got removed, so those have more space for fuel.

Answer (score 5):

The aircraft is equipped with seven (7) integral fuel tanks:  five (5) Center body fuel tanks and two (2) wing tanks.  Center body fuel tank #2 serves an an engine feeder tank with all other tanks transferring fuel to it via a network of fuel pumps for consistent weight and balance.  The aircraft can be refueled by means of a single pressure refueling receptacle located in the port main landing gear well.

[image]

[image]

(Source: Luftwaffe MiG-29 Flight manual)

Comment: Thanks this is the explanation I was looking for